# Laravel query run twice

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel spatie package for query builder and when I run my query it shows in the telescope that it runs twice the only difference between them is this line:

```
select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `accommodations`
where
.
.
.rest of my query
```

and the other one is like this :

```
select
  *
from
  `accommodations`
where
.
.
.
limit
  10 offset 0
```

any idea what is wrong here because every one of those queries takes about 5 sec and that would be about 10 to 12 second extra for me. thanks

## EDIT

```
  $data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
            ->allowedFilters([
                AllowedFilter::scope('bed_count'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('filter_price'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('filter_date'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('discounts'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('grade_stars'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('city_id'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('is_recommended'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('accommodation_type_id'),
                'name',
            ])
            ->allowedAppends(['cheapestroom'])
            ->allowedIncludes(['gallery','city','accommodationRooms','accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistorySearch','discounts','prices'])
            ->allowedSorts([
                AllowedSort::custom('discount', new DiscountSort() ,'amount'),
                AllowedSort::custom('price', new PriceSort() ,'price'),
            ])

            ->paginate(10);
```

this is my spatial query builder and this is the part that takes 5 secs twice :

```
class DiscountSort implements Sort
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property) : Builder
    {
        $direction = $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        $data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'accommodation_rooms.accommodation_id')
            ->join('discounts', 'accommodation_rooms.id', '=', 'discounts.accommodation_room_id')
            ->select('accommodation_rooms.id')
            ->orderBy('discounts.amount', 'desc')
            ->select('discounts.amount', 'accommodations.*')
            ->groupBy('discounts.amount', 'accommodation_rooms.id')
        ;
        return $data;
    }
```

Its a join and because laravel and this package are not able to order data by relationship or nested relationship value I should have used a join.

Can that second query be the cause of pagination ??

Comment: Share your model and controllers

Comment: Those are two different queries. Why would they automagically be "merged" / executed as one?

Comment: @shihab check my edited code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `paginate`, the pagination needs to know how many records are in the full result, to display all the needed informations; therefor is the `count` query.
The second one gets the results for the current page of your pagination ;)

Comment: One word to your runtime. Get your executed sql and execute it in your db with an `explain` right before it. There you get a good base for knowing, where to put some indexes on your columns to speed up your query. It's all in the index ;)